# iOS Resizing images for thumbs?

Tags: iphone, image-resizing

I am kinda new to handling images, there are many things that I do not know, so bear with me. Basically I take image with camera, and present it inside `UIImageView`, which is small view 60:80. Image is automatically resized to fit `UIImageView`, and everything looks fine.

My question is - Do I need to do some more image operations (is order to maximize efficency), or that's all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resize` `image` `function` would be:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(CGSize)imgSize
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgSize);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
  UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return newImage;
}
```

`Save` resized image in `document directory` with `unique names`. Later `access thumbnail image` from `document directory`.

If count of images is `more` than use `lazy loading` of images to display images.

Answer (score 6):

Please use following code which will gives you better thumbnails

```
  -(UIImage *)generatePhotoThumbnail:(UIImage *)image 
  {
    CGSize size = image.size;
    CGSize croppedSize;
    CGFloat ratio = 120.0;
    CGFloat offsetX = 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = 0.0;

     if (size.width > size.height) {
        offsetX = (size.height - size.width) / 2;
        croppedSize = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.height);
     } else 
         {
        offsetY = (size.width - size.height) / 2;
        croppedSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width);
     }

     CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(offsetX * -1, offsetY * -1, croppedSize.width, croppedSize.height);
     CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], clippedRect);

     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio, ratio);

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
     [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] drawInRect:rect];
     UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
         CGImageRelease(imageRef);

     return thumbnail;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the way the picture is displayed, then you don't need any additional code. Image views have no problems rescaling images for you and they are quite efficient at that, so don't worry about it.